# Control vlc process in java

Tags: java, vlc

I am wondering if there is any way to control the windows vlc app in c++. 
My purpose is to control the video and perform functions like pause, resume, stop, volume etc.

Comment: c++ or java ? .. either correct the tag or question

Answer (score 1):

[vlcJ](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) is one such option. The vlcj framework uses JNA to bind to the vlc native library. This requires that the run-time environment is properly configured so that your Java application is able to locate the vlc native library. Here is a [Tutorial](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/tutorial1.html) to get you started with it.